# glLoadMatrixf seemingly not working

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having an issue with `glLoadMatrixf`. It does not appear to be loading the
given matrix properly. I am debugging this by checking the matrix using
`glGetFloatv()`.

```
float modelMatrix[16] = {
  1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 5, 1
};

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glLoadMatrixf(modelMatrix);

GLfloat m[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
```

When debugging in Visual Studio 2013, m returns as

```
m 0x004aeb50 {-107374176., -107374176., -107374176., -107374176., 
              -107374176., -107374176., -107374176., ...}
```

This leads me to believe that the matrix is not being loaded properly.

I am using OpenGL version 4.0.12874, freeglut, and glew. Based on my searches
online, this is the standard way of loading a custom matrix. I am at a loss.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your current matrix mode, i.e. the argument of the last `glMatrixMode()` call?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I've updated the original question. I am using `GL_MODELVIEW`.

Comment: The code here looks fine to me. I suspect that something is in a bad state when this code is reached. As wild guesses, it could be that you have no current context. Or you're using a core profile context, where these functions are not available anymore. Or there is an error condition in earlier code. Are other calls working? Did you try calling `glGetError()` before/after this code?

Comment: The contents of `m` are just a bunch of 0xCC bytes, if that helps. I'm curious; are you calling `glGetFloatv` after a call to `glBegin` and before the corresponding `glEnd`?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Before I call `glMatrixMode`, `glGetError` returns 1280. After `glMatrixMode` the error is 1282. After `glLoadMatrixf` the error is still 1282. After `glGetFloatv` the error is 1280.

Comment: @warrenm I am not using `glBegin` or `glEnd`. My rendering loop uses `glDrawArrays` which successfully renders the points I put in there. I can't seem to get the perspective to change until I figure out why the modelview and projection matrices aren't loading properly.

Comment: @warrenm is probably on to something. From the error descriptions of `glMatrixMode()`: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glMatrixMode is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd."

Comment: If you're not using `glBegin/glEnd`, I'm back to one of my earlier guesses: Are you sure that you have a compatibility profile context where these deprecated calls are still supported? Are you successfully using any other legacy features with the same context?

Comment: I am starting to think that there is no context at all. I am using freeglut. The window is created successfully, but none of these GL calls work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, I called `glutInitContextVersion(4, 1);` when initializing my window. Doing this resulted in an error 1282 being shown after every applicable GL call.

I changed the init to `glutInitContextVersion(3, 1);` and everything is now working properly. `glGetError` now returns 0 after all applicable GL calls.

Comment: For future readers: This is because the OpenGL matrix functions (and quite a lot of other stuff) is depreciated in 3.1 and removed in 3.2+ unless you ask for a compatibility profile.